# After user Sign In, why Devise redirect to sign_in view instead of specified path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I have a problem with Devise redirect. By default after user sign in and sign up it will be redirect to`root_path`. I want to change that path to `playlists_path`.

Every time I run my test, it fails and it goes to `users/sign_in` path, I don’t’ know why. I have tired different solution found on Stackoverflow and Github, but nothing works. May be the solution is obvious and I can’t see it, or my test is not written well. Strangely enough `sign_up_spec` pass, but `sign_in_spec` fails every-time. I need another eye and help.

**UPDATE*****

Based on "sevenseacat" comments, I have updated my test below, but still get same result.

**routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users
  root to: 'homes#index'
  resources :playlists, only: [:index, :new]
end
```

**sessions#new**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

**registrations#new**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

**Application_controller**  Where [Devise advice](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out) :) to change the redirect after user sign in

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
    def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
     playlists_path
    end
end
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "someone#{n}@example.com" }

    factory :user do
      email
      password 'password'
      password_confirmation { |u| u.password }
  end
end
```

**spec/factories/users.rb**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
# require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'database_cleaner'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.order = "random"

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

**spec/features/sign_up_spec.rb** This spec is good and pass

```
require 'spec_helper'
feature "Sign up as a user" do

  scenario "with an email address" do
    user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
    visit root_path
    click_link "Create Account"

    fill_in "Email", with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    fill_in "Password confirmation", with: user.password_confirmation
    click_button "Sign up"

    expect(current_path).to eq playlists_path 
    expect(page).to have_css '.alert',          text: 'Welcome! You have signed up successfully.'  
    expect(page).to have_link 'Sign out',       href: destroy_user_session_path
    expect(page).to have_link 'Edit profile',   href: edit_user_registration_path
  end
end
```

**spec/features/sign_in_spec.rb** This spec is no good and fails

```
require 'spec_helper'
feature "Sign in as a user" do

  scenario "with an email address and password" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    visit root_path
    click_link "Sign in"

    fill_in "Email", with: user.email
    fill_in "Password", with: user.password
    click_button "Sign in"

    expect(current_path).to eq playlists_path
    expect(page).to have_css '.alert',          text: 'Signed in successfully.'    
    expect(page).to have_link 'Sign out',       href: destroy_user_session_path
    expect(page).to have_link 'Edit profile',   href: edit_user_registration_path
  end
end
```

When i run `rspec spec/features/sign_in_spec.rb`, it fails:

```
Failures:

  1) Sign in as a user with an email address and password
     Failure/Error: expect(current_path).to eq playlists_path

       expected: "/playlists"
            got: "/users/sign_in"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/features/signin_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The weird thing is, although my sign_in_spec fails but when I run the app, it works well and after Sign In and Sign Up the redirect to `playlists_path`

Why devise doing that weird redirect OR why my test fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By executing these operation:

```
bundle exec rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=test
bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test
bundle exec rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test
```

and change

`user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)`

to

`user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)`

my test is passed.

Answer (score 0):

Does that user exist in the sign in spec? Likely, you will need to create the user with that email and password in the setup for that spec.

Specs are generally run in isolation and the data is all removed between tests - if you are relying on data to be present when running a spec, you need to set it up in the spec.